# Hide a single DIV out of multiple DIV with same id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a DIV in my page but there is no id for the DIV.
There is only class for the div which is common to other DIV too .

Please help me how i can hide only a single DIV based on the 'for' attribute of the label tags

below is the DIV

```
<div class="field-group aui-field-versionspicker frother-control-renderer">
<label for="versions">Affects Version/s</label>
</div>

<div class="field-group aui-field-versionspicker frother-control-renderer">
<label for="fixVersions">Fix Version/s</label>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `id` attribute visible in your code. And `id`s must be unique.

Comment: Why I am getting down votes ?????? I cant even upvote the answer I like

Comment: @mizan, you can upvote once you have 15 reputation. However, you can Accept an answer that you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('.field-group').eq(0).hide(); //hides first div
$('.field-group').eq(1).hide(); //hides second div
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaA7u/2/) is the fiddle

**updated**

```
$('label[for="fixVersions"]').parent().hide();  //hides fixVersions with label selector
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaA7u/6/)

Comment: Hi steve thanks for the quick reply , I need to hide the second div but on some pages the order might change , is it possible to hide the dive based on label value ?????

Comment: ok yes.... i was hiding the label... there should be `parent()` thanks @arttronics..

Comment: You are awesome @bipen . You solved my issue with minutes thanks alot dude :)

Comment: :).. done.. upvoted your question... .before asking question make sure u clear everything regarding your question.... or mostly u will be getting downvote for the question u asked...it is better if u provide some of the codes that u have worked on...

Comment: Hey bipin sorry i still cant vote up your anwers and comments .... Once again thanks , this issue was on a very high priority for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You just cannot use same multiple `id` for elements, instead you can use same class for multiple elements and you are using same class that is fine:

You can do with these ways:

```
$('.field-group:eq(1)').hide();
```

and

```
$('.field-group').eq(1).hide();
```

and

```
$('.field-group:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

so all of the above script will hide the `second div`.

**Note:**

`.eq()` or `:eq()` are `0` indexed while `:nth-child()` is `1` indexed.

Comment: Hi Jai ,the number of DIV can increase and the order can change in the web application (JIRA) , so I need to hide the DIV based on the label value

Comment: `label value` dont get it. you mean `for="versions"` like this.